# htmlagilitypack delete spaces

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am processing a html file but the source has lot of spaces.

```
                    <span itemscope itemtype="Company">







            <h3 class="headingLink">
                COMPANY


                    <span itemprop="name"><br/>Kroger</span>

            </h3>


              <span itemprop="streetAddress">607 Moores Mill Rd</span><br/>
              <span itemprop="addressLocality">Huntsville</span>
              <span itemprop="addressRegion">AL</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">35811</span>
              <br/><br/>

             </span> <!-- end itemscope company -->
```

```
                    <span itemscope itemtype="company">








            <h3 class="headingLink">
                COMPANY2

                    <span itemprop="name"><br/>North Militia</span>

            </h3>


              <span itemprop="streetAddress">225 N. Militia Dr</span><br/>
              <span itemprop="addressLocality">Lawrenceburg</span>
              <span itemprop="addressRegion">TN</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">38464</span>
              <br/><br/>

             </span> <!-- end itemscope company -->




                    <span itemprop="telephone">981-112-5521<br/></span>
                    <a rel="nofollow" id="aboutThisPhoneNumber9" href="javascript:void(0);" 

onclick="changeDisplay('/locator/locator/QuickHelp.do?

startsWithFilterProperty=about.this.phone.number&amp;openedItemProperty=about.this.phone.number9', 'quickHelpBox', 

'clickQuickHelp', event);return true;" class="dottedLink">About this phone number<span class="ada_hidden">-981-112-
```

5521

```
                <strong>Company Hours</strong>
                <br/>
```

Lobby:

```
    <!-- Set request scoped variable expected by daysOfWeekRange.jsp -->













































    Mon-Thu





9-4,


    <!-- Set request scoped variable expected by daysOfWeekRange.jsp -->





























   Fri




9-5,


    <!-- Set request scoped variable expected by daysOfWeekRange.jsp -->













































    Sat-Sun




















            COMPANY open 24 hours




        <br/>(visitors need to call in)
```

I want the to store name,address,phonenumber, company hours in a table. So, i tried

```
HtmlDocument hdoc = new HtmlDocument();
hdoc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
hdoc.LoadHtml(searchResult);
HtmlNodeCollection divCon = hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"resultInfo\"]");
 string[] ct = new string[divCon.Count];
for (int m = 0; m < divCon.Count; m++)
 {
  if (divCon[m].InnerText.Trim().Contains("Company Hours"))
    {
       int ctr = divCon[m].InnerText.Trim().Replace("\n", " ").Replace("<!-- Set request scoped variable expected by daysOfWeekRange.jsp -->","").Replace("  "," ").Replace("</br>","").IndexOf("Branch Hours");

                if (ctr > 0)
                    ct[m] = divCon[m].InnerText.Trim().Replace("\n", " ").Replace("<!-- Set request scoped variable expected by daysOfWeekRange.jsp -->", "").Replace("  ", " ").Replace("</br>", "").Substring(ctr, 499);

            }
```

I am still getting empty spaces. How can I remove it?

Thx
Rashmi

Comment: what you expect to get exactly given this sample html?

Comment: To print span itemprop = "streetAddress","addressLocality","addressRegion","postalCode","telephone" and Company Hours which will be stored in database

Comment: please provide the link to the page you wish to scrape.